# Silverlight - access ListBox item properties through XAML only

Tags: silverlight, xaml, properties, listbox

Does anyone know how to access the items stored in a `ListBox`, and their respective properties, for use elsewhere?

This is what I have so far:

First, the code to create a list of checkboxes from available columns in a grid.  This works as it should:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="testBoxes" ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, ElementName=radGridView}" Grid.Column="1" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"  Content="{Binding Header}" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The problem is, I want to create a new list of items, and I want it to be populated by items from the previous list above, but only if the checkbox for a respective item is checked, so:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=testBoxes}" Grid.Column="4" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding checkBox.Name}" IsChecked="{Binding checkBox.IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

This will generate the right number of checkboxes, but they will not have tables and do not respond to their counterparts being checked or not.

Obviously the code for things such as `checkBox.Name` and `checkBox.IsChecked` is wrong, but I have not had any luck in working out what the right code is.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, this feels like a pretty simple problem but it's been bugging me for the past half an hour or so.

Comment: ViewModel and CollectionViewSource, You should use this technics on your code-behind. This may take more hours firstly but then you gain more hours.

Comment: I would greatly prefer the binding to be done through XAML, hence the question title.  I have for now made do with a work around by binding to the original grid, and checking if a particular column is visible (as the first list of check boxes determine column visibility).  However I am now stuck with the issue of trying to do `Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=OneWay}"` as although `IsVisible` is a boolean, `Visibility` is not.

Comment: Add one thing IValueConverter. Implement this as("BooleanToVisiblityConverter.cs") and add it to your Binding shown Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisiblityConverter}}"

Comment: In the end, I used `<telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />` declared inside of my `UserControl.Resources` tags.  Then for the control itself I used `Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}`.  I believe there is also a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` that is part of `System.Windows.Controls`, but my inexperience with XAML meant I couldn't work out how precisely to use it with my project, but the Telerik one will suffice and performs as I want it to.

Comment: With regard to what you suggested, when you say `BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs`, are you suggesting I implement my own way of handling the conversion in a separate C# file?

Comment: Yes it can be a separate or inner class. I suggest separate ,you will use it for many cases. Yeah,I'm sure implementation will be easy for you. Just add this class to your resources before InitializeComponents by this.Resources.add("BooleanToVisibilityConverter",new BooleanTovisibilityConverter()); the other parts are the same. Good luck :)